# Delaying main thread execution until no lock exists on other threads: best practice?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am wanting to delay part of main thread execution the time other thread is not locked.
The following code seems to work as intended, but I am wondering if it is the good/best way to do it (I am totally new to threading).

For the context: new_status_grid method creates a new grid in wxpython, and the modify_simu_status method modifies some cell values in the current grid, and is executed as a separated thread.
I want to avoid conflicts between grid creation and grid cell writing.
There is a sleep in the thread method to limit usage of external resources needed by modify_simu_status.

```
# somewhere in the main thread
class SimuStatus(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        # some code
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.modify_simu_status, daemon=True)

    def new_status_grid(self):       
        # some code here
        while self.lock.locked():  # wait for threads lock to be released
            pass

        # main thread acquires the lock, preventing modify_simu_status code to be executing
        self.lock.acquire()

        # destroying previous grid, if any
        if self.grid_created:
            for child in self.sizer.GetChildren():
                widget = child.GetWindow()
                if isinstance(widget, wx.grid.Grid):
                    widget.Destroy()

        # some other code, that must not been executed if other threads are ongoing
        self.lock.release()

        # first time method is used, the thread is started
        if not self.thread.is_alive():
            self.thread.start()

    def modify_simu_status(self):
        """This is the thread launched by the main thread, running ad vitam"""
        while True:
            self.lock.acquire()
            try:
                # some code that can conflict with new_status_grid code
                self.lock.release()
                time.sleep(refresh_time)  # during this delay, the lock is released
            except BaseException as e:
                self.logger.error('Exception in status panel scan thread: %s ' % e)
                self.lock.release()
                time.sleep(refresh_time)
```